# $\pi$-Group Problem

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G$ be a finite group and $\pi$ be any set of prime numbers. A finite group $H$ is a $\pi$-group if all primes that divide $|H|$ lie in $\pi$.

> a. Prove that $G$ has a unique normal subgroup $N$, minimal with the property that $G/N$ is a $\pi$-group.
>
> b. Let $f : G \rightarrow G/N$ be the canonical homomorphism. Show that for any homomorphism $g$ of $G$ to a $\pi$-group is of the form $g = fh$ for some homomorphism $h$.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this problem is with a good definition (it feels like a cheat!).

Let $N$ be set of all elements that are in the kernel of *every* homomorphism $G\to H$ for all $\pi$-groups $H$. By definition, $N$ is invariant, thus normal, which takes care of (a). The second part is also a triviality, since $N$ is in the kernel of any such map.

*EDIT*: An alternative solution is to take the intersection of all normal subgroups that contain all elements prime to $\pi$.

Comment: I am a bit confused by the phrase "Element that is in the quotient of a homomorphism". I'm sure your answer is right, I just don't quite catch the meaning.

Comment: @Arthur That's a typo. I meant to say kernel.